# Css border around li, but not encapsulating sublists

Tags: html, css, nested, html-lists

I want to surround multi line li text with a border.

I also want to:
1) Make the border only wrap around each element, like it does on the Root element
[Solved!] 2) Make the border stop where the text stops, not stretching out to the side
3) Add some spacing between each element's border.

Illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CygtA.png

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="root">
    Root
  </li>
  <li>
              Lorem ipsum<br>dapibus neque<br>Tincidunt mauris
        <ul>
          <li>Adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
          <li>Vestibulum </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Aliquam</li>
  <li>
    Dapibus
    <ul>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
$maincolor: #F76464;

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;

  li {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid $maincolor;

    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      left: -15px;
      top: 0px;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      border-left: 1px solid $maincolor;
      height: 1em;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $maincolor;
      width: 10px;
    }

    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      left: -15px;
      bottom: -7px;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      border-left: 1px solid $maincolor;
      height: 100%;
    }

    &.root {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;

      &::before {
        display: none;
      }

      &::after {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    &:last-child {
      &::after {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aky4hwtn/31/

This far, I've tried using different display types, padding, encapsulating the text with a div tag etc with not much success.

Comment: 2) can be solved with `li {float: left; clear: left;}`, and 3) with `margin:some spacing;` but I'm not sure what you mean with 1).

Comment: Thank you. I've made this picture to illustrate point 1 and 3. https://i.imgur.com/o6jd4rK.png

Comment: As for margin: this breaks up the hierarchical tree that connects the nodes (the directory-like lines to the left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your 3 problems as follows:

1. Wrap only the text, not any sublists, with a `<div class="node">{text}</div>`. The `node` class applies a border and as it only wraps the text and not the sublists the border only goes around the node. To make it look nice I added a bit of `padding`.
2. The new wrapping `<div class="node">`s would use the full width, therefore `display: inline-block` is applied to the `node` class only using the space that is necessary.
3. The `node` class has a `margin-bottom` to gain some space below. To account for that the sizing of the `before`/`after` elements had to change.

I excluded the root from the list, because otherwise there would be a `<li>` for the root that has a sublist with all of the rest which doesn't make much sense to me.

The before and afters still overlap a bit, maybe this can be improved with more finetuning of the sizing, but everything looks fine with the given example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 10px;
}

li:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.node {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="node">
  Root
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="node">Lorem ipsum<br>dapibus neque<br>Tincidunt mauris</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="node">Adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="node">Tincidunt mauris eu risus.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="node">Vestibulum</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="node">Aliquam</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="node">Dapibus</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="node">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="node">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you managed to solve issue number 1? I want to understand css better :)

Comment: @Nattfrosten I updated my answer to directly address your three problems